# Google AdWords Invalid HTTP Response Codes

Tags: iframe, google-ads-api, http-response-codes

Trying to advertise a website on Google Adwords, I got "disapproved" due to 'Invalid HTTP Response Codes'.

The website runs fine as far as I can see. I **suspect** this may happen due to using iframes, which contain "3rd party" websites, which may produce errors over which the advertised parent website has no control (you can examine the actual website http://ambatya.com).

Can this be the case? And if so, do I have any quick method for solving this without compromising the website's functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use individual landing page for the Adwords.

Because I saw your website and it have 4 different section like Animal, Cultur & Art, Food and Fashion.

And according to Google Adwords Policy

They will not approved your page if your page have hatred; violence; harassment; racism; sexual, religious, or political intolerance, or organizations with such views content that's likely to shock or disgust, content that's exploitative or appears to unfairly capitalize at the expense of others.

Then It will not approved and as far I can see that your website have many pictures within the iframe which inappropriate.

For More detail please check it

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6316?hl=en

https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/6008942?hl=en#con

If still you have any issue let me know.

Comment: I'm starting to doubt whether this is the problem at all. Google Webmaster Tools show as if my home page is "not found"... ALL counters are zero, and even when I attempt the "Fetch as Google" feature, I immediately get a "Not found" status... But in practice both ambatya.com and www.ambatya.com ARE found...

Comment: Firstly set any one url either with "www" or without "www" then reverify your Google Webmaster Account put that code in the header and again fetch your URL then Google will display your URL.

Comment: This has turned into an intriguing puzzle... I did everything you suggest and when trying "Fetch as Google" I still get "Not found" after a second. What in my HTML or JavaScript can cause this?

Comment: Huh... When I add "index.html" to the "Fetch as Google" -- it is FOUND. What can I learn from this?

Comment: FOUND IT. There was an old hack that changed my .htaccess and affected things. I hope I got rid of it now.

Comment: may be you have any static page for the Home page. Still you you can used the same technique as mention above apart from it or either you can add me in your webmaster then i can easily check it. my email id is kumarvivekyours@gmail.com

Comment: If its not work please let me know so that i can help you.

Comment: Note I actually found the problem. I got "not found" status **in search engines only** because apparently someone hacked my site and modified the '.htaccess' file to invoke something else for search engines...

Comment: Hope now it's fine and you got the access of the site. If Still you have problem let me know.